# Enable Proguard while exporting AAR file in release mode

Tags: android, proguard, aar

We all know ,ProGuard gets enabled when we export the APK in release mode.
 but i have some requirement that i need to give aar file to client ,so i want to know ,how to enable ProGuard while exporting aar file in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Open your api project in a new project and set your proguard file and build your apk in release mode.

In your Gradle module file

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }